# While running cmake, `No CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER found` error

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

I am trying to build OpenBLAS from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/), following [these](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio) instructions. After running

```
cmake .. -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=flang -DBUILD_WITHOUT_LAPACK=no -DNOFORTRAN=0 -DDYNAMIC_ARCH=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
```

The error generated is:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The ASM compiler identification is unknown
-- Didn't find assembler
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    clang-cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  No CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "ASM" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Warning: Did not find file Compiler/-ASM
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/OpenBLAS_0.3.10/xianyi-OpenBLAS-63b03ef/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/OpenBLAS_0.3.10/xianyi-OpenBLAS-63b03ef/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

After a bit of googling, I found this webpage: [Assembler](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/languages/Assembler)

It does not specify how to resolve this issue. How to solve it?

Comment: The **first error** you got is about `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and you should resolve this error first before resolving other errors. You run the command from the step 6, but step 5 tells you to **activate** MSVC environment. Have you performed this step? How **exactly** have you activated the MSVC environment?